# Can Python find path automatically?

Tags: python, windows, automation, directory, path

So, my idea is, if I just throw a python script into a folder, for example this:

```
path = r"C:\Users\[name]\Downloads"

print("This:", path, "is your path")
```

Can I tell Python to find the folder the script is in, and fill the **path** variable by itself, without having to manually add the path?

I've tried with these:

```
os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
```

and

```
"\n".join(sys.path)
```

But didn't get the results I want.

*Information:

- I'm using Python 3.9
- Windows 10*

Comment: It would be nice if you could add a sample response in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I use `pathlib` library to deal with path-related operations in python3.X.

You can try this :

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
```

You can read more about the library here :
https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html